# ITable<T>.DeleteAllOnSubmit() is absent?

Tags: c#, .net, itable

As far as I see `ITable<T>` interface doesn't have `DeleteAllOnSubmit()` method that exists in `ITable` interface and in `Table<T>` class.

I am going to implement on my own something like this:

```
public static void DeleteAllOnSubmit<T>(this ITable<T> table, IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    entities.ForEach(entity=>table.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
}
```

Question 1: Is there any pitfalls here? If it was so easy Microsoft would implement that thierselves...

Question 2: Why that was not implmemented out-of-the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look at the implementation of `Table<TEntity>.DeleteAllOnSubmit<TSubEntity>()` shows, that there isn't much more going on:

```
public void DeleteAllOnSubmit<TSubEntity>(IEnumerable<TSubEntity> entities) where TSubEntity: TEntity
{
    if (entities == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("entities");
    }
    this.CheckReadOnly();
    this.context.CheckNotInSubmitChanges();
    this.context.VerifyTrackingEnabled();
    foreach (TEntity local in entities.ToList<TSubEntity>())
    {
        this.DeleteOnSubmit(local);
    }
}
```

So, I'd say: Your implementation is just fine.
BTW: There is no `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could implement something to the effect of..

```
public static void DeleteAllOnSubmit<T>(this ITable<T> table, IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    table.Context.GetTable<T>().DeleteAllOnSubmit(entities);
}
```

Just traveling through the `ITable<T>` to the context specific table and calling its `DeleteAllOnSubmit()`. That way there isn't the deviation in the way you enumerate and delete all and the way the context does natively.